# Cloud-SDK Filter by subfields

Tags: s4sdk

I'm using **S4 Cloud-SDK** to make queries on SAP S/4 Hana and I trying to get information about Business Partners filtering with company code. The fields that I'm looking for are:

- Supplier FullName
- Supplier Email
- Tax1 Number
- Representative Name
- Supplier Code

For that I'm using **BusinessPartnerService** to get these fields. The problem is, I'm doing lots of queries to get this information and I would like to reduce the number of queries to the database. One of the queries is listed below.

```
List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners = businessPartnerService.getAllBusinessPartner().select(
    BusinessPartner.TO_SUPPLIER.select(Supplier.TO_SUPPLIER_COMPANY),
    BusinessPartner.TO_BUSINESS_PARTNER_CONTACT, BusinessPartner.TO_BU_PA_IDENTIFICATION, 
    BusinessPartner.TO_BUSINESS_PARTNER_ADDRESS, BusinessPartner.TO_BUSINESS_PARTNER_TAX, BusinessPartner.ALL_FIELDS)
    .execute();
```

Is it possible to filter the query above using an EntityLink? For example, something similar to the following:

```
.filter(BusinessPartner.TO_SUPPLIER.select(
        Supplier.TO_SUPPLIER_COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE.eq("ABCD")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as of today, filtering on expanded 1:1 navigation properties is not yet supported. We'll update this question once we have more information!

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking forward for that functionality.

Comment: Version 2.8.0 is available as of today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Version 2.8.0 and above support 1:1 navigation properties.